# Errors whenever I try to use a method

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple python script to trick my friend into thinking get is going to get a virus unless he writes the password p3nis47 but whenever I try to run it I get errors at lines 17, 4, and 9. 17 and 4 are just methods and I don't know why I'm getting errors and at 9 I'm just subtracting 1 to the count to make sure I only give my friend 3 tries to type in the "password". Sorry if it's really obvious, I just started learning python.

```
count = 4
def ask():
    answer = input("do you wan't a virus ")
    respond(answer)
def respond(response):
    if(response == "p3nis47"):
        print("congrats!!! you don't have a virus")
    else:
        count = count - 1
        if(count == 0):
            print("trololololololololololol")
        print(answer,"is not a vailid answer")
        print("you have ",count," attempts remaining")
        ask()
ask()
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: You only posted 15 lines of code, making it tough to see the problem in line 17.

Comment: You might wanna `quit()` once `count==0`

Answer (score 2):

Running your program with bad input gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c.py", line 15, in <module>
    ask()
  File "c.py", line 4, in ask
    respond(answer)
  File "c.py", line 9, in respond
    count = count - 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

That's because you are using a global variable but you need to let python know about it. Add `global count` to the start of the function. Then there is another error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c.py", line 16, in <module>
    ask()
  File "c.py", line 4, in ask
    respond(answer)
  File "c.py", line 13, in respond
    print(answer,"is not a vailid answer")
NameError: name 'answer' is not defined
```

That's simple too. You just accidentally used the wrong variable name. The working script with two changes is

```
count = 4
def ask():
    answer = input("do you wan't a virus ")
    respond(answer)
def respond(response):
    global count
    if(response == "p3nis47"):
        print("congrats!!! you don't have a virus")
    else:
        count = count - 1
        if(count == 0):
            print("trololololololololololol")
        print(response,"is not a vailid answer")
        print("you have ",count," attempts remaining")
        ask()
ask()
```

So, I ran the fixes... but now I've got a virus!

Comment: Thanks, this really helped